# Aurora Writer and Reader internal replication (replica lag) time

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-aurora

We are using Amazon RDS.

There are 2 RDS-server, 1) Writer 2) Reader.

I want to check the internal cloning time between writer and reader.

For ex.
From writer connection, one record has changed so at the same time if reader connection retrieves that record which is changed by the writer.

so when that change is reflected in the reader?

Or how much time is required by AWS RDS reader to get all changes made by the writer.

For more information check attached screen-shot for reader and writer form AWS-RDS.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html

> AuroraReplicaLag
>
> For an Aurora Replica, the amount of lag when replicating updates from the primary instance, in milliseconds.

This is the metric that you should be looking at to track this. Its usually under 100ms.